# Compiler error info : No matching function for call to FUNCTION(TYPES ARGS) with unused typename template

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, compiler-errors, fixed-size-types

I have had an issue with this bit of code, and compiler info didn't help much.

I have a structure where I define an unsigned int array in a structure :

```
struct TypeHolder {
    uint8_t byte_size;
    uint8_t values[8]{ 0 };

    TypeHolder() {
        byte_size = 0;
    };
    
    uint16_t calcCRC() {
      return Faster_CRC16(values);
    };
};
```

And a function `Faster_CRC16` which goes as follows :

```
template <typename any_type>
uint16_t Faster_CRC16(uint8_t* data_string_litteral){
  /* bunch of stuff */
    uint8_t b = data_string_litteral[j - 1]; // access an item of the array through indexation
  /* bunch of stuff */
  return crc_data;
};
```

When compiling this on Arduino and VisualStudio2019 (compiler MSVC), both returns error message :

> no matching function for call to 'Faster_CRC16(uint8_t [8])'

It is a strange info, as `uint8_t values[8];` is supposed to be equivalent to `uint8_t* values;` in the fact that both represent a variable holding a pointer to an address.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]. The code you've shared does not produce the error your describe. See https://godbolt.org/z/sT7fbYzjq

Comment: May depend on your compiler/compiler options. For me, with g++ (GCC) 10.2.0 compiles correctly without any error nor warning.

Comment: Ok, i finally got this, it is in fact related to a template ``<typename any_type>`` header that was sitting on top of the function from a previous version. As i didn't used any_type inside my function, i didn't even payed attention to that for about an hour now...but it seems to have solved the issue... I didn't know it could cause trouble if not used ! I'm sorry for the time i took to both of you for this question. Thank you very much, i actually found out that by copy pasting the code into Arduino instead of Visual Studio, following your compiler version advice, user8225026. Good night !

Comment: Recommendation: Put together a complete example of the problem in the question so that future readers have can see the cause and effect and then self-answer. This fits better with the expected format of a Stack Overflow question than dropping an explanation of a solution in an incomplete question. Worse future readers may not be able to understand how you got from A to B, making the answer not useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation, it turns out the issue was related to the template header that was sitting on top !

```
template <typename any_type> //guilty piece of code
```

Even unused, these can cause trouble. It is a realy stupid inattention/lazyness error, but at least knowing that it could happen may be valueable to you.